# Hanami: Does the form helper autofill nested colllections?

Tags: hanami

According to the guides the Hanami form helper automatically fills fields with the right value, even for nested fields. Is this also true for nested collections? It’s not currently working for me, this is the rough structure of my params:

```
{
  user: {
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Smith",
    posts: [
      { title: "A Title", body: "Some text."},
      { title: "Another Title", body: "Some more text."}
    ]
  }
}
```

And the fields:

```
<input type="text" name="user[posts][][title]">
<input type="text" name="user[posts][][body]">

<input type="text" name="user[posts][][title]">
<input type="text" name="user[posts][][body]">
```

Are they supposed to be being autofilled?

Comment: https://gitter.im/hanami/chat this is the best place for hanami related questions

Comment: I asked there too :)

Comment: Can you please share the code that you use in your app?